# Доступ ссылки <a> по времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Представление:**

```html
<p><a href="~/Files/МА_2_кл_Работы.rar">МА_2_кл_РАБОТЫ</a> <em>*будут доступны 28 апреля, 08:00</em></p>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы данная ссылка была доступна 28 апреля в 08.00 (собственно как и написано в описании). Как это сделать?

Не могу ничего найти в сети по этому поводу. Разве, что необходимо [использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520263/how-to-disable-href-link-and-enable-the-link) `class="disabled"`. Но как поставить таймер на установку данного атрибута?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Управлять безопасностью пряча ссылки - глупо. Прежде всего, надо сделать так чтобы сам файл "МА_2_кл_Работы.rar" был недоступен раньше указанной даты. Это основы безопасности.

---

Что же до ссылки - то что вам мешает просто написать `if`, коли вы пользуетесь ASP.NET MVC? Зачем вообще таймер - пользователь что, будет сидеть несколько дней с открытой страницей?

Вот вариант простой проверки даты:

```
<p>
  @if (DateTime.Now >= new DateTime(2016, 4, 28, 8, 0, 0)) {
    <a href="~/Files/МА_2_кл_Работы.rar">МА_2_кл_РАБОТЫ</a>
  } else {
    <text>МА_2_кл_РАБОТЫ </text><em>*будут доступны 28 апреля, 08:00</em>
  }
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Время доступа нужно ограничить на сервере. Возвращаемую ошибку обработать и показать на клиенте.

Дополню: файл при этом скачивать не обязательно, достаточно отловить статус XHR-запроса по `onreadystatechange` и прервать запрос.

Comment: Какой клиент и возвращаемая ошибка? У него по ссылке, очевидно же, просто файл скачивается.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, файл скачивается с сервера, Павел. Запрос на загрузку возвращает ответ с ошибкой - одна часть решения. Вы же сами в своём ответе именно это и предлагаете. Дополнительно можно не отображать ссылку вообще, если используется серверная шаблонизация.

Comment: Файл скачивается браузером, а не скриптом. Скрипт не сможет получить код ошибки, чтобы ее обработать.

Comment: Элементарно, в обработчике клика по ссылке:

    $.ajax({
       url: downloadUrl,
       type: 'POST',
       success: function() {
           window.location = downloadUrl
       }
});

Comment: Вы предлагаете два раза скачивать крупный архив?! Тогда уж лучше HEAD кидать.

Comment: Это поведение обрабатывается и можно только проверить файл на доступность, но это тема для другого вопроса.